# Интерес дело тонкое, Петруха… (правильная запись текста)

Tags: запятые, стилистика, тире, выбор-варианта

Недавно я использовала этот текст в своем рассуждении, по аналогии с известной **[песней](https://yandex.ru/video/preview/15649474423690366213).**

Мысль была такая: **интерес** аудитории непредсказуем и неустойчив, зависит от неясных причин и часто меняется. Мысль не понравилась, запись текста тоже. Причем раскритиковали **оба** письменных варианта (мой и тот, что в песне).

**Текст песни:** *Восток – дело тонкое, Петруха,  / Восток, как капризная старуха.*

**Мой текст:** *Что такое интересно или неинтересно? Интерес дело тонкое, Петруха,  интерес, как капризная старуха.*

А как **правильно** записать, можно ли объяснить **оба варианта**?  И дополнительный вопрос: в моем варианте **кавычки** где-нибудь нужны (при цитировании по аналогии)?

Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем запятая перед "как"? Зачем "или"? Вы же не предлагаете выбрать одно из двух.

Comment: По поводу запятой перед _как_ согласен, она не нужна, это сказуемое

Comment: Запятая перед КАК самая спорная. В песне делается явная пауза, но она может быть "музыкальной". Я тоже хочу сделать паузу, у меня такой смысл: Интерес такой, какой бывает капризная старуха. Фильм был: Год, как жизнь. Тоже писали по-разному. Кроме того, здесь можно применить "именительный темы" по образцу: Интерес, он как капризная старуха. То есть есть возможности уйти от однозначного правила. К тому же у Розенталя сказано: обычно тире не ставится перед союзом КАК. P.S.Пожалуйста, отвечайте в поле ответа, а я вам плюсики поставлю за интерес к теме))

Comment: Ну у вас там "или", а не "и". Если номинатив, то да, не сказуемое и запятая. Но это соответствует не вашему, а следующему: *Интерес, такой как капризная старуха.* Улавливаете разницу? То есть не про любой интерес, а именно про такой. То же и с названием фильма. Говорится не про год в принципе, а именно про такой год (один из). Про паузы. Можно перед каждым словом делать паузу, это не значит, что перед каждым словом надо поставить запятую. Подлежащее и сказуемое никогда запятой не разделяются. Это один из столбов пунктуации.

Comment: (1) Любой вопрос:, тот или этот. Что такое интересно или (что такое) интересно?   Улавливаете? (2)  Столбы, говорите?   Интерес ТАКОЙ! Вот вам сказуемое. Без запятой. Аккуратно обходим столбики. Абдула был так хитёр...

Comment: Так вы предлагаете выбрать один вопрос из двух? (2) не понял. Вам же надо с запятой.

Comment: Аа, если хотите паузу, то ставьте тире — тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Только так. А с запятой номинатив, который здесь не подходит по смыслу.